# VueJS - VueChart JS not getting updated on store.dispatch

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have something like accepting parameters from a form and submitting. On submit, I dispatch an action and return the response and assign them to the parameters of the chart. But the change is not happening unless i press the submit button twice. But when i press the submit button, the label is getting updates as there is a v-model linked to the label select. But since there is no v-model for the bar-chart component, it is not getting updated.

```
 <template>
  <v-container fluid>     
     <v-card class="small" v-if="!empty">
        <bar-chart :chart-data="datacollection"></bar-chart>
    </v-card>   
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  import BarChart from './BarChart.js'
  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

  export default {
    name : "TestLegPerformance",
    components: {
      BarChart
    },
    data: () => ({   
      startdate: null,
      enddate: null,
      startmodal: false,
      endmodal: false,
      datacollection : {         
          labels: [],
          datasets: [
            {
                label: '',
                backgroundColor: '#C58917',
                data: []
            }
          ]
        },
      selected: [],     
      empty: true 
    }),
     computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
        planNames: "planNames",
        details: "details" //parameter that i return from getters
        })
    },
    mounted () {
        this.getAllPlanNamesAction();
    },

    methods: {
      ...mapActions(["getAllPlanNamesAction","getDetails"]),    


      //assigning values to the chart parameters
      changeData(){
        this.empty = false;
        let collectionClone = Object.assign({}, this.datacollection);
        collectionClone.datasets[0].label = this.selected;
        collectionClone.labels = this.details.months;
        collectionClone.datasets[0].data = this.details.sub_count;
        this.datacollection = collectionClone;
        console.log('Collection Clone: ',collectionClone)
      },

     // form submit action 
      submitAction(){
        this.empty = true;
        console.log("Plan: ",this.selected);
        console.log("Start Date: ",this.startdate);
        console.log("End Date: ",this.enddate);        
        this.$store.dispatch('getDetails',
         [this.selected,this.startdate,this.enddate])
        this.changeData();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, it's a little unclear what your actual question is. On the second click is the chart updating? In that case, are you trying to figure out how to get it to happen on the first click, or are you just wondering why the first click isn't updating it? Also, you've included a lot of code; have you considered trying to reduce it to a [MCVE]? Oftentimes simplifying the code like that can help you localize the error/erroneous behavior to just a certain segment, making it easier for you to ask a more direct question.

Comment: yeah I want it to update the chart at the first click of submit. And edited the code. On the first submit, changes are happening at the chart label but not the data. On the second click , it is getting updated .

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs?

Comment: yes i am @MahmudAdam

Comment: Did you review this as well http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=reactive-data?

Comment: yeah i did and I couln't find an appropriate solution for this @MahmudAdam

Comment: Could you please provide an example containing the ./BarChart.js file and the relevant vuex module preferably on https://codesandbox.io/ or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Take a look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/2p9v32wo5y?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FBarChart.vue

Comment: Let me know if you get anything @MahmudAdam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.js and Vue Chart.js are not reactive by default. 
See this in the [Vue Chart.js docs](http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home?id=reactive-data)

[See this example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/3j73wmjzq?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

Comment: Is there any way that i can do it without setting Interval ? @Cristi Jora ?

Comment: That was just an example to see that it updates. Just call your function (generateData in my case) whenever you want to update the chart

Comment: I did and it doesn't seem to work. It worked only when i set some interval in monuted()

Comment: Make sure you initialize it first time.
https://codesandbox.io/s/yknmk8or1z

Comment: The issue is that I am having a submit buttom which takes the parameter from three fields and doing a submit where i am dispatching an action, mutating it and returning it to the vue. The thing I want to do is, once i do a submit , it should get the object from axios and update the chart at the same click. @Cristi Jora

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of tries, I got it to work by redirecting the submit button to two different functions and adding a timeout between those two functions.